# TkInter icon is not working after converting to .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

could someone please tell me why I am getting this error after converting my Python file into an executable?

The Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MD2HTML.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2109, in iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined
[5572] Failed to execute script 'MD2HTML' due to unhandled exception!

[process exited with code 1]
```

Pyinstaller command:
`pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icon.ico MD2HTML.py`

My code:

```py
from tkinter import messagebox
import markdown
from tkinter import *

def go():
    result = markdown.markdown(md.get("0.1",END))
    root.clipboard_append(result)
    messagebox.showinfo("Information", "HTML CODE COPIED SUCCESSFULLY")

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
root.geometry("700x510")
root.title("MD2HTML")
root.config(bg="black")

title = Label(root, text="MD-2-HTML",bg="#20B2AA",fg="white",font = ("Cascadia Code", 25))
title.pack(fill=X)

information = Label(root, text="Enter Your MD Code To Convert To HTML",bg = "black", fg="white")
information.pack(fill=X)

md = Text(root,borderwidth=0,bg = "#222222",fg = "white", insertbackground="#20B2AA",font=("Cascadia Code",9))
md.pack(pady=10)

go = Button(root, text = "Convert", border=0, command=go, bg = "lightgreen", activebackground="cyan")
go.pack(pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

OS: `Windows`
Python: `3.10`

Thank you!

> PS: In my code editor, that is VSCode, it's working fine...

Comment: Since you're using the `pyinstaller` `--icon` command line argument, you probably don't need the `root.iconbitmap()` call in your script.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a function to get the temp path for your exe file while it is running. Please check this link for details.

[Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741)

PS. I am using Pycharm, so I am not familier with VSCode. The pyinstaller command that I use is (you need to put your icon file and your py file in same folder):

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --clean --icon='icon.ico' --add-data 'icon.ico;.' MD2HTML.py
```

If you use Mac/Linux/Unix, please change 'icon.ico;.' to 'icon.ico:.'

You can check [Adding Data Files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) for more information about *.spec file while using pyinstaller.

The code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import markdown
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os


def go():
    result = markdown.markdown(md.get("0.1", END))
    root.clipboard_append(result)
    messagebox.showinfo("Information", "HTML CODE COPIED SUCCESSFULLY")

# This function can get temp path for your resource file
# relative_path is your icon file name
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


root = Tk()
iconPath = resource_path('icon.ico')
root.iconbitmap(iconPath)
root.geometry("700x510")
root.title("MD2HTML")
root.config(bg="black")

title = Label(root, text="MD-2-HTML", bg="#20B2AA", fg="white", font=("Cascadia Code", 25))
title.pack(fill=X)

information = Label(root, text="Enter Your MD Code To Convert To HTML", bg="black", fg="white")
information.pack(fill=X)

md = Text(root, borderwidth=0, bg="#222222", fg="white", insertbackground="#20B2AA", font=("Cascadia Code", 9))
md.pack(pady=10)

go = Button(root, text="Convert", border=0, command=go, bg="lightgreen", activebackground="cyan")
go.pack(pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

The resource_path function code is copied from [the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741) which is showed above and writed by stack overflow user [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889973/max).

Hope this can help you.

I have tried the code and there is no issues with it. Please make sure your pyinstaller version is up-to-date.

BTW: **--icon=icon.ico** command is for the exe file, and **root.iconbitmap()** in the code is for the icon that shows in the app window title bar(top left corner of the app window). They are **not** same.